# Formula for finding maximum 3 values, even if cell value is empty

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have 4 columns with values. I want to sum best of three from them. What formula I should write?

If the value in any of the columns is empty or not a number, its value for the purpose of the calculation should default to 0.

Examples:

```
| 4| 2| 1| 3|  (2,3,4 are best, sum = 9)
| 4| 1|AB| 5|  (1,4,5 are best, sum = 10)
|AB|AB| 6| 7|  (0,6,7 are best, sum = 13)
| 1|AB|  |  |  (0,0,1 are best, sum = 1)
```

How do I make a non-number field default to a number value for calculations?
How do I sum just the best 3 of the four columns?

Comment: did not down-vote, but can maybe see why it was, Question title, does not actually match the problem, and the actual problem only becomes clear in the comments. Now that you have your answer, you may want to edit your question so it reflects the full problem (possible 'AB' values etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer that accounts for possible non-numbers in cells  (Empty is also a non-number)

```
=SUM(A1:D1)-MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,0),IF(ISNUMBER(B1),B1,0),IF(ISNUMBER(C1),C1,0), IF(ISNUMBER(D1),D1,0))
```

`ISNUMBER(_cell_)` returns true for numbers, but false for anything else.

---

Answer that accounts for Empty cells:

```
=SUM(A1:D1)-MIN(IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,A1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),0,B1),IF(ISBLANK(C1),0,C1),IF(ISBLANK(D1),0,D1))
```

`ISBLANK(_cell_)` can be used to check if a cell has a value, `IF(bool, value_if_true, value_if_false)` can be used to choose between two values depending on the boolean value.

---

Original Answer:
This is not portable for I want best X of Y fields, but does Best Y-1 out of Y

```
=SUM(A1:D1)-MIN(A1:D1)
```

where your values are in columns A, B, C, D

Comment: This does not work if a value is not actually entered (Empty != 0)

Comment: This seems to be same answer what Vinnie gives.

Comment: My cells are not blank but they are having value 'AB'.

Comment: @Himadri, When I typed the answer in, there were no answers yet. Did not notice the new answers before I submitted. Updated to work with empty cells, matino's answer is easier to read, less error prone, and more versitile though.

Comment: @Himadri Updated with a version that treats non-numbers as 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick solution if you only have four values and want to dump the lowest.  Your range is A1 through A4.  Sum them all and subtract the lowest value of the group.

```
=SUM(A1:A4)-MIN(A1:A4)
```

This will sum the values where the cells are not "AB"

```
=SUMIF(C1:C4,"<>AB")-MIN(C1:C4)
```

If you want to SUM all values, except for the absent students ("AB"), then remove the subtracted value.

```
=SUMIF(C1:C4,"<>AB")

C1 = 2.5
C2 = AB
C3 = AB
C4 = 3
SUMIF = 5.5
```

This formula looks at each cell, assigns a 0 if the value is "AB", then subtracts the lowest value from that range.

```
=SUM(IF(C1="AB",0,C1),IF(C2="AB",0,C2),IF(C3="AB",0,C3),(IF(C4="AB",0,C4)))-MIN(IF(C1="AB",0,C1),IF(C2="AB",0,C2),IF(C3="AB",0,C3),(IF(C4="AB",0,C4)))
```

Comment: Suppose values in 4 columns are 2.5, AB, AB, 3 then the answer should be 5.5 but it is showing 3. I have to write AB incase student is absent.

Comment: Added something to take out the minimum value.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It's working if you want to subtract the smallest value.  I've updated the answer to only sum values that aren't "AB"

Comment: Simple sum is OK with SUM function only. I want to substract minimum from these four values which is the problem.

Comment: What I wrote isn't pretty, but it works for what you're asking for.  Mr.Mindor's will do a similar comparison using the ISNUMBER() function, which you could also use here.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(LARGE(A1:A4,{1,2,3}))
```

Where A1:A4 is range of the first row

Comment: AB is not a numeric value, which the LARGE function is expecting.  You'll either need to substitute a value in there or use Mr.Mindors solution.  My post just takes the minimum actual number and subtracts it.

Comment: if you are using your 2.5, AB, AB, 4 on this, then LARGE still tries to grab the first three numbers, but there are only two. so #NUM! is inserted as the third...